# Display a transient ripple animation for multiple touches using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, touch-event

I have done this earlier with UIKit using `touchesBegan(_:with:)`, but now I'm wondering how to achieve this same effect while using only SwiftUI (if possible). Here's the example of how it should look like:

[image: touch-ripple-resized.gif]

Key points are:

- display a small circle at each touch location (on touches began)
- automatically animate scaling and fading of the circle
- repeat for all touches on the screen (at the same time)

Answer (score 2):

While writing this question, I came up with this solution:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var touches: [Touch] = []

    struct Touch: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let location: CGPoint
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            ripplesLayer
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onEnded { value in
                    touches.append(
                        Touch(location: value.location)
                    )
                }
        )
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

    var ripplesLayer: some View {
        ForEach(touches.suffix(5)) { touch in
            RippleView()
                .position(
                    x: touch.location.x,
                    y: touch.location.y
                )
        }
    }

    struct RippleView: View {
        @State private var isHidden = false
        @State private var size: CGFloat = 50

        var body: some View {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.white.opacity(isHidden ? 0 : 0.5))
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .transition(.opacity)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5))
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation {
                        isHidden = true
                        size = 200
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but I still have some questions:

- this solution doesn't support multiple touches at the same time, is that even possible to achieve with SwiftUI?
- if multiple touches happen at the same time, in UIKit at least one of those would be registered, while in SwiftUI `DragGesture` will sometimes completely skip to call `onChanged` or `onEnded` callbacks - is this a bug?
- what's a completely different approach for solving this (I'm curious)?

Answer (score -1):

**I tried to simulate ripple efect in Material Design.**

struct RippleView: View {

```
@State private var touchLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
@State private var touch: Bool = false
@State private var color: Color = Color.clear
@State private var size: CGFloat = 1000 


var body: some View {
   
    ZStack {
        Color(red:1,green:0.32,blue:0.33).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    
            VStack {
                Text("Material Design\nRipple Efect").multilineTextAlignment(.center).font(.title)
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 500, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.white)
          
            
            .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .onChanged { value in
                              touchLocation = value.location
                                print(touchLocation)
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                print("animasyon")
                                color = Color.black
                                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5)){
                                    touch = true
                                }
                                
                               
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                                   touch = false
                                    color = Color.clear
                                   
                                }
                                
                                
                                
                            }
                    )
          
            .overlay(Circle().fill(color.opacity(touch ? 0.0 : 0.2))
                        .frame(width: touch ? size: 0, height: touch ? size: 0, alignment: .center)
                        .position(
                            x: touchLocation.x,
                            y: touchLocation.y
                        )
            )
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(20.0)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0.0, y: 4.0)

            
        
        
    }
}
```

}